# Multithread chunks of a file and reassemble

Tags: python, multithreading, multiprocessing

I need to break up large 15 Gb files, so they can be processed as chunks in parallel, reassembled (in order), and saved. This code works to a point, it splits the files into equal sizes for as many threads as specified then launches those threads.

The problem is only one or two threads are running while the rest are stopped, even though the file is fully loaded into memory. I am using `.map` because asynchronous multiprocessing or multithreading will not preserve the order as I understand.

I have spent way too much time on this, and written this code 4 different ways according to examples on this site. Is there a way to parallelize this?

The simplified code:

```
import multiprocessing

def load_mod (arg, p):
    with open (arg, 'r') as fp:
        fp = fp.readlines()
        fp = [fp[i:i + (len(fp)//p)] for i in range(0, len(fp), (len(fp)//p))] #make p# of chucks
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(p)
    results = pool.map(process, fp)
    sname = arg.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '_fmt.' + arg.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
    with open (sname,'w') as f: f.write("".join(results))

def process (filebits):
        newfile = ''
        for l in filebits:
           ###process large amount of text line by line here and append to newfile
        return newfile

process_list = [#A list of files#]
for i in process_list: load_mod(i, #number of processes#)
```

Comment: `(len(fp)//p)` should be `math.ceil(len(fp)/p)`, otherwise you're creating at least `p` work units, not exactly `p` work units.  Also, pass `processes=p` on the `.Pool` call to create that many workers.

Comment: @AnonCoward: Using `pool = multiprocessing.Pool(p)` _is_ creating `p` number of worker processes.

Comment: Right you are, misread it, sorry about that.

Comment: @heatherfuke: Is your question about mutiprocessing or multithreading? (e.g. processes or threads) They're not the same thing in Python and not interchangeable.

Comment: Multiprocessing, I know they are different. Multiprocessing also runs multiple threads though.

Comment: You may need to add a `if __name__ == '__main__':` line before the last two lines (which will then need to be indented) for your multiprocessing code to work properly (depends on OS). Multiprocessing does use multiple threads internally to do what it does, but they're largely not your concern.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Warning**

Passing such large amounts of data to subprocesses has a fair amount of overhead involved with it. Unless function `process` is very CPU intensive, very little will be gained by using such a multiprocessing divide-and-conquer strategy for this problem.

---

The following code should work. I have taken the liberty of renaming some of your variables to what are more meaningful (at least to me) names. I have also tried to optimize some of the code trying to avoid recreating the pool multiple times. I am also avoiding repetitive string concatenation operations. So it's a tradeoff: replacing multiple string concatenations in function `process` with multiple file writes in function `load_mod`. I have also provided a `split` function that divides an input file of lines into an even number of chunks (at least as evenly as possible):

```py
import multiprocessing


def load_mod (pool, n_processors, file):
    with open (file, 'r') as fp:
        # split the lines in n_processors chunks:
        line_chunks = split(fp.readlines(), n_processors)
    sname = arg.rsplit('.', 1)[0] + '_fmt.' + arg.rsplit('.', 1)[-1]
    # imap allows results to be processed as they are returned
    # and you do not need them all in memory at once:
    new_line_chunks = pool.imap(process, line_chunks)
    # do not join results, just write out each piece:
    with open (sname, 'w') as f:
        for lines in new_line_chunks:
            for line in lines:
                f.write(line)
            # or maybe replace preceding two lines with: f.write(''.join(lines))

def split(a, n):  # function to split a list in n even parts
    k, m = divmod(len(a), n)
    return list((a[i * k + min(i, m):(i + 1) * k + min(i + 1, m)] for i in range(n)))

def process(lines):
    # repeatedly appending to strings is inefficient; just append to new_lines
    new_lines = []
    for line in lines:
        ###process large amount of text line by line here and append to newfile
        new_lines.append(processed_line)
    return new_lines

if __name__ == '__main__':
    # number of processors on this computer:
    n_processors = multiprocessing.cpu_count()
    # create the pool once!
    pool = multiprocessing.Pool(n_processors)
    file_list = [""" file list """]
    for file in file_list:
        load_mod(pool, n_processors, file)
```